# Floating point system

Tags: floating-point

there exists a floating point system (B, T, L, U) (B=base, T=number of digits, L=lower exponent, U=upper exponent) where pi is exactly represented? And for the number 8/7?

Comment: Do you want to consider systems where the base is not an integer?

Answer (score 1):

There is not. The floating-point systems you are considering can only  represent numbers of the form k· B^n, where k and n are integers.  All these numbers are rational, but π is irrational.

For a floating point system that can exactly represent 8/7, you need B to be a multiple of 7, in which case it is easy; you write it as 8·7^{-1}.

Comment: For pi I was thinking that its not possible, but not sure. For 8/7 yes was so stupid. Anyway thank you

Answer (score 1):

Of course there does.  In base-pi floating-point, pi is exactly `10.0`.